# count longest series of chars next to each other in a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I am a beginner in c++,I need to be able to find longest series of chars (that are next to each other) in a string that will be inputted by user,how can I do that, I have been trying for hours to type the code and nothing worked for me.
Sorry for my Bad English

example: 
"**....*****......"(string input)
I need to find the longest series of '*'
so the input will be 5
problem(need to count just the chars between 'S' and finish at 'F')

```
int cnt=0,cnt1=0,cnt2=0;
string s;
cin>>s;
for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
    if(s[j]=='S')
        cnt1++;

    if(s[j]=='F')
        break;
    while(true) {
        if(s[j]=='*'&&cnt1==1)
            cnt++;
        if(cnt>cnt2)
            cnt2=cnt;
        if(s[j]=='F')
            break;
    }
    cnt=0;
}
cout<<cnt2<<endl;
```

Comment: Show the code that didn't work, and explain how it doesn't work. We may be able to help.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your English is good enough for this site, it doesn't need to be perfect. Your code, too, does not need to be perfect, but you should include it anyway. It is both easier and more productive to help you fix your error than to give you a working code.

Comment: As long as the previous character is the same as the present character, increment the counter.  You should maintain the starting position, character and the quantity of contiguous characters.  You could also maintain a set of these values that are the "maximum" or throw them into a `std::vector` then sort by sequence length.

Comment: Did you write out the algorithm the code was expected to follow before writing code? It's very hard to debug both code and algorithm at the same time. And it's very hard to debug code if you don't know what algorithm it's supposed to be following.

Comment: The `while` loop will never end unless `s[j] == 'F'` before the loop starts.

Comment: it worked without the while loop ,thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume you are trying to find a series of equal chars (like "aaa").
A simple method, probably not the most efficient, is to count those chars in a loop and hold the index of the longest set of chars.

1. Get your string from stdin
2. Create an index counter and a variable to count current number of chars
3. Count same chars in a loop in one int and mark their beginning index (only if sum is greater than the last one you encountered in loop)
4. After the loop return the char (and same following chars) in string[index]